# Where should I call my update map function?I need to call it after my Async Task?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask

Hi I 'm new to Android programming and I have an app that when  user clicks on a country it starts another activity displaying an a map with a  marker locating the capital city.

But I need to get the  capital from my async task method.So it needs to return country info and then I can update my map.I called my update map method in onPost Execute but the app just crashes?

In my on Create

```
 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync( this);


    new GetCountryDetails().execute(selectedCountry);
```

Then in my Async task

```
private class GetCountryDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, CountryInfo> {

    @Override
    protected CountryInfo doInBackground(String... params) {
       CountryInfo countryInfo = null;
```

In my onPostExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute(CountryInfo countryInfo) {
    countryCapital=countryInfo.getCapital();

    updateMap(map);//doesn't work here
```

onMapReady:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

updateMap

```
         public void updateMap(GoogleMap map){
    LatLng capitalCity = getCityLatitude(this, countryCapital);
       map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(capitalCity));

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(capitalCity).title( countryCapital);
        map.addMarker(marker);

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated thank!

I

Comment: `onPostExecute` is supposed to run on the main UI thread, so updating the Google Map from there should be completely legitimate (I do this in my app and it works).  What does look strange to me is that you are passing `map` as a parameter to `updateMap()`.  Why are you doing this?  I have the Google Map as an activity level field.

Comment: @sook Lim share your error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create Map varible as activity field.And define variable in onMapReady function.After that use activity variable as you want. I think it should works.

GoogleMap map;

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    this.map = map;
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below code snippet works perfectly for me. Please try it out.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<LatLngBean> arrayList;
private ArrayList<LatLng> listLatLng;
```

add below code in onPostExecute method

```
LatLngBean bean = new LatLngBean();
bean.setTitle(jobj.getString(""));
bean.setSnippet("Hello, " + jobj.getString(""));
bean.setLatitude(jobj.getString("latitude"));
bean.setLongitude(jobj.getString("longitude"));
arrayList.add(bean);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
  public void run() {
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(YourActivity.this);
  }
});
```

and then add below code onMapReady() method

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
        try {
            listLatLng = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                final LatLngBean bean = arrayList.get(i);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(bean.getLatitude());
                double lon = Double.parseDouble(bean.getLongitude());

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);

                BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.salesman_map_icon);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(bean.getTitle())
                        .snippet(String.valueOf(i))
                        //.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
                        .icon(icon));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
                LatLng object = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                listLatLng.add(object);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```